# VBA code not working in UFT

Tags: vba, hp-uft

I really need your help for an issue I am stucked on since 3 hours...
I have a VBA code that open IE and navigate to an URL.
The code seems to work when I test it within Microsoft Visual Basic :

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
        Set app = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        MsgBox "OpenWindow 1 : " & Err.Number
        app.Visible = True
        app.Navigate ("salut.com")
        result = Err.Number
        MsgBox "OpenWindow 2 : " & Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If result <> 0 Then
        Call test
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works properly in an Excel macro but whenever I execute the exact same code in UFT (Unified Functionnal Testing) it throws errors :

- error -2147467261 after the createObject (?)
- error 238 after the navigate (which I think is quite normal since
  createObject fails)

The code is quite the same, I just pass the URL to navigate to to the function :

```
Function openWindow(url)
    On error resume next
        Set app = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        app.Visible = true
        app.Navigate(url)
        result =  Err.number
    On error goto 0
    If result <> 0 Then
        openWindow (url)
    End If
End Function
```

I really have no idea of what the issue is...

Comment: I think you may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201704191432562970515). And then declare `url` as `ByVal url As String` so the function can only take a `String`. Right now we don't know for sure whether the `Navigate` call is failing because you're giving it something it can't handle - an explicit `String` parameter would make things less ambiguous. Seems UFT can't handle `CreateObject` calls?

Comment: Also your function is recursive, and will invariably blow up the call stack given any invalid `url`, or if *anything* goes wrong.

Comment: UFT can handle `CreateObject` calls just fine, but it uses `vbscript` so you can't explicitly declare `url As String`.  I've tried the code above in UFT and it works fine for me...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround :

```
Function openWindow(urlToNavigate)
    SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe",urlToNavigate
End Function
```